Technical Term for Multivariate Time Series Forecasting with different input output features?
What is the technical name for multivariate time series forecasting where the input and output features are different? usually, the dimensionality of the input and output is the same when we use the term forecasting.
For example my time series dataset has features A,B,C,D. I want to forecast just D based on A,B,C features. what would I call this problem? Thanks in advance!

Hi @aseembits93, Welcome to the community. Please consider upvoting or marking the answer as correct if you find anything helpful in the community.

We call it Vector Auto Regression - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression

from the definition it seems like we are regressing y_t from y_t-p uptil y_t-1. what i'm referring to is regressing y_t from x_t-p uptil x_t-1 where x is some other time series feature.

dynamic regression might be the closest relevant term

It is a normal forecasting problem, with D's historical features as Nans (could be 0s).
This way you can forecast D using your favorite algorithm.
